# Button style not working in Safari

Tags: safari, css

I have the following CSS3 style:

```
.shiny-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
    width: 15em;
    padding: .5em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    border: solid thin #882d13;
    -webkit-border-radius: .7em;
    -moz-border-radius: .7em;
    border-radius: .7em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #bbb;
    background-color: #ce401c;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e9ede8), to(#ce401c),color-stop(0.4, #8c1b0b));
}

.clicked {
    background-color:gray;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;
}
```

Style `.shiny-btn` works, but `"shiny-btn clicked"` is not working in Safari 5.0.5.

Do you know why?

Comment: How are you applying the classes to your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e9ede8), to(#ce401c),color-stop(0.4, #8c1b0b));
```

This line is inherited when you have `class="shinybtn clicked"`. And it *override* both `clicked` properties.

```
.clicked {
  background-color:gray;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;
  background-image:none;
}
```

This fix it.